# How do I make my React-Native Android project ready for 64-bit architecture?

Tags: android, react-native

I have a React-Native app that I deploy to Google Play store. I've received the message notifying that I need to offer a 64-bit version of my app.

I added `ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'` to my app's `build.gradle`, so now the `apk` includes the 64-bit versions of some of the libraries I use. However, this does not happen for most of the libraries.

In my `apk`, I see in `lib/x86`:

```
libjsc.so
libicu_common.so
libgnustl_shared.so
libreactnativejni.so
libimagepipeline.so
libyoga.so
libfolly_json.so
libfb.so
libglog.so
libglog_init.so
libprivatedata.so
```

I don't even know what exactly each of these is. What are the steps I can take to find out what they are and if they offer a 64-bit version?

Comment: The duplicate answers my question: need to upgrade RN to 0.59.